# Running linux container on docker windows

Tags: linux, windows, docker

I installed Docker for windows on a windows 10 box. It required me to enable the HyperV feature on it. Everything installed correctly and is running fine.

Although one thing took me by surprise. I am actually able to run a linux container on docker windows. I thought cross-containerization is not possible conceptually. Can anyone please help me understand how does this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HyperV is used to spin up a Linux VM to run containers. Docker is still running Linux containers under the covers, the native Windows containers are still being developed.

Comment: Hmm interesting. So, HyperV role comes with some stock linux VM image that is used in such cases? If possible, can you please guide me to some documentation that explains all such internals. Thanks.

Comment: No, it's Docker for Windows that installs the VM image, with Docker already configured. Here are [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) and here is [the code](https://github.com/docker/for-win).

Comment: Not relevant to the OP, but for others that follow, Windows Server 2016 has now been released which includes support for native docker containers. See [Docker's partner page](https://www.docker.com/microsoft) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you are running a Linux Container on a Linux Machine rather than Windows. Windows runs a VM in Hyper-V when you download the Docker for Windows. You can open Hyper-V Manager and see a Linux VM will be running. Currently Docker for Windows is in beta which supports the Docker natively which needs Windows 10 build no. greater than 14393.222 or a Windows Server 2016.