# How does a Windows or non Linux OS container work in Docker?

Tags: docker

How does a windows container in a docker system run on top of a Linux host. Who handles the system call translations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running linux container on docker windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39662925/running-linux-container-on-docker-windows)

Comment: @DavidMaze I understand how linux containers are actually run on a Linux VM in a windows host. My question was about how windows containers are able to run on a Linux host?

Comment: @SamJawahar Never heard of running windows container on linux, could you share some article to let us learn together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from the Windows Server Core image documentation:

> [Windows requires the host OS version to match the container OS version](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore)

In short, your proposed scenario doesn't work. You need to run Windows containers on a Windows host.